# Passive vs active voice

Tags: passive-voice, present-perfect

I came across this sentence in a test:

> The first computer was built in 1943, but since then the computer technology has developed a great deal.

My confusion is can we use *has been developed* instead of the active form of present perfect? If not, can you help me clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

Develop is a verb that is "ergative". This means that there are two senses, one is transitive and one is intransitive.

Another ergative verb is "to open".  We can say

> The door opens   (intransitive ergative)

> John opens the door (transitive)

> The door is opened   (transitive passive)

Note the similarity between transitive-passive and intransitive. The difference is that the transitive passive implies that the door didn't open "by itself".  Someone did it.

With your example we could use

> Computer technology has been developed...

But this would imply that  "Someone developed computer technology"   The writer wants to suggest that it developed "naturally", as a result of many actions. So they use the intransitive-ergative.  It doesn't carry the unwanted meaning  "Somebody has developed computer technology."

Comment: :) The term 'ergative' is new to me; it was interesting as I checked its meaning!